# Redirecting all of one subdomain's traffic to HTTPS via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Using .htaccess, is it possible to redirect `http://www.mydomain.com` and `http://mydomain.com` to HTTPS, while NOT redirecting `http://staging.mydomain.com` or `http://127.0.0.1`?

Also, what will happen to any POST data that goes through the redirected portion? Will it remain insecure, or will it also be encrypted?

Comment: POST data will be discarded when redirecting, by the way. It'll be insecurely transmitted, then lost in the redirected request as it becomes a GET.

Comment: Is the solution to this to use relative paths or "//" instead of "http://" / "https://"?

Comment: Why not use https to begin with? The rewrites should be there incase someone types in http, but links on your site or forms should probably just be https.

Comment: I suppose that's the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going. Once redirected by apache, all data is processed through https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```